# Overiding inherited functions

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class `Object` and some derived classes, eg `class Bird : public Object`.   The functions `Object::Render` and `Bird::Render` are defined and implemented.  (as a matter of fact, `Bird::Render` calls `Object::Render`)

I also have a `vector<Object*>` which is holding a bunch of `Bird*`s.  Now, in the future, this vector will also hold other types of objects.

My question is: without knowing the type of an element of that vector, is it possible to execute its specific `Render` function, ie can

```
vector<Object*> objects;
object.push_back(new Bird());
// ...
objects[i]->Render(); // This should execute Bird::Render
```

As far as I can see, the last line only executes `Object::Render` (which makes sense, as to the calling function, this is a vanilla `Object`).

Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object::Render` should be `virtual function` and `Bird` should override `Render` function.

```
class Object
{
public:
   virtual ~Object() {}
   virtual void Render() = 0;
};

void Object::Render() {}

class Bird : public Object
{
public:
   void Render() { Object::Render(); }
};

vector<Object*> objects;
objects.push_back(new Bird());
objects[0]->Render();
```

Comment: He mentioned that Bird::Render calls Object::Render, so it might not be pure virtual, or you might show how pure virtual functions can be defined.